# Beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From the following URL: https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793
I would like to web scrape 3 specific things:

- The value for "Bruttofortjeneste" which is given in the field in the top of the website
- "Branchekode" and the string below that (further down the page)
- "Antal ansatte" and the string below that (further down the page)

At the moment i have the following code:

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

bruttofortjeneste_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'field'}, string='Bruttofortjeneste')
if bruttofortjeneste_elem:
bruttofortjeneste_value = bruttofortjeneste_elem.find_next_sibling('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip()
else:
bruttofortjeneste_value = 'N/A'
antal_ansatte_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'label'}, string='Antal ansatte')
if antal_ansatte_elem:
antal_ansatte_value = antal_ansatte_elem.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
else:
antal_ansatte_value = 'N/A'
branchekode_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'label'}, string='Branchekode')
if branchekode_elem:
branchekode_value = branchekode_elem.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
else:
branchekode_value = 'N/A'

print('Bruttofortjeneste:', bruttofortjeneste_value)
print('Antal ansatte:', antal_ansatte_value)
print('Branchekode:', branchekode_value)
```

---

However this returns N/A for the bruttofortjeneste and seems like it cannot be found. It does work for antal ansatte and branchekode. I imagine the reason that bruttofortjeneste cant be found could  be due to the data being within a field which is nested in other classes etc. or something else. I am new to python so i am having a hard time.

Can someone help me with a code that works for bruttofortjeneste and the value?

From the code above i get the following results:

N/A for bruttoresultat
the correct answers for the other 2 parameters. So overall i just need help to scrape the value for bruttoresultat.

Best regards
A big noob

Comment: Hello Scott Hunter

do you have anything specific in mind that you would like to have elaborated? The HTML code or anything else?

Comment: Your code, as posted, is not valid Python, due to lack of indentation.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bruttofortjeneste is not in https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793 response HTML. It is request from https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793?period=1129436a6b479abc232731e824879d23 in Javascript.

```py
def get_bruttofortjeneste():
    url = 'https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793?period=1129436a6b479abc232731e824879d23'
    headers={
        'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.57'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    print(response.text)
    bruttofortjeneste_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'field'}, string='Bruttofortjeneste')
    if bruttofortjeneste_elem:
        bruttofortjeneste_value = bruttofortjeneste_elem.find_next_sibling('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip()
    else:
        bruttofortjeneste_value = 'N/A'
    return bruttofortjeneste_value
```

EDIT

Sorry, I forget to test.
This new request need http header `x-requested-with`. I updated the code.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_bruttofortjeneste():
    url = 'https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793?period=1129436a6b479abc232731e824879d23'
    headers={
        'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.57'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    bruttofortjeneste_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'field'}, string='Bruttofortjeneste')
    if bruttofortjeneste_elem:
        bruttofortjeneste_value = bruttofortjeneste_elem.find_next_sibling('div', {'class': 'value'}).text.strip()
    else:
        bruttofortjeneste_value = 'N/A'
    return bruttofortjeneste_value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://ownr.dk/companies/public-profile/34883793'
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    antal_ansatte_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'label'}, string='Antal ansatte')
    if antal_ansatte_elem:
        antal_ansatte_value = antal_ansatte_elem.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
    else:
        antal_ansatte_value = 'N/A'

    branchekode_elem = soup.find('div', {'class': 'label'}, string='Branchekode')
    if branchekode_elem:
        branchekode_value = branchekode_elem.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
    else:
        branchekode_value = 'N/A'

    bruttofortjeneste_value = get_bruttofortjeneste()

    print('Bruttofortjeneste:', bruttofortjeneste_value)
    print('Antal ansatte:', antal_ansatte_value)
    print('Branchekode:', branchekode_value)
```

Comment: Hello Scccboom

Many thanks for your response. I am very new to python and am not entirely sure how the full code should be. I have tried adding your element but it seems to still return N/A for bruttofortjeneste :)

Comment: Hello @scccboom

Many thanks for the provided code! it helps a lot